# exit command does not work properly in my own shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, exit

I wrote a shell for an assignment and it works correctly,  but there is a small run time error which i can not figure out.  When the user enter the command 'exit' through the shell it should come out of newly created shell.  But the problem is I have to type the command 'exit' several times to quit the shell. If someone can help me it will be a great pleasure for me!  Thanks all!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* cmndtkn[256];
char buffer[256];
char* path=NULL;
char pwd[128];

int main(){

//setting path variable 
    char *env;
    env=getenv("PATH"); 
    putenv(env);

    system("clear");

printf("\t MY OWN SHELL !!!!!!!!!!\n ");
printf("_______________________________________\n\n");

while(1){

    fflush(stdin);
    getcwd(pwd,128);
    printf("[MOSH~%s]$",pwd);

    fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
    buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';

    //tokenize the input command line   
    char* tkn = strtok(buffer," \t\n");
    int i=0;
    int indictr=0;

        // loop for every part of the command
        while(tkn!=NULL)
        {
            if(strcoll(tkn,"exit")==0 ){
                exit(0);                
            }

            else if(strcoll(buffer,"cd")==0){

            path = buffer;
            chdir(path+=3);}

            else if(strcoll(tkn,"|")==0){

            indictr=i;}
            cmndtkn[i++] = tkn;
            tkn = strtok(NULL," \t\n");

        }cmndtkn[i]='\0';

// execute when command has pipe. when | command is found indictr is greater than 0.
    if(indictr>0){

    char* leftcmnd[indictr+1];
    char* rightcmnd[i-indictr];
    int a,b;

        for(b=0;b<indictr;b++)
        leftcmnd[b]=cmndtkn[b];

        leftcmnd[indictr]=NULL;

        for(a=0;a<i-indictr-1;a++)
        rightcmnd[a]=cmndtkn[a+indictr+1];

        rightcmnd[i-indictr]=NULL;

    if(!fork())
    {   
        fflush(stdout);
        int pfds[2];
        pipe(pfds);

            if(!fork()){

                close(1);
                dup(pfds[1]);
                close(pfds[0]);
                execvp(leftcmnd[0],leftcmnd);
                }   
            else{

                close(0);
                dup(pfds[0]);
                close(pfds[1]);
                execvp(rightcmnd[0],rightcmnd);
            }

    }else wait(NULL);

//command not include pipe 

        }else{

        if(!fork()){
            fflush(stdout);
            execvp(cmndtkn[0],cmndtkn);

        }else wait(NULL);

        }

}

}
```

Comment: FWIW I reproduced your error once but it proceeded to work fine on subsequent runs.  There are a number of small errors as Jonathan points out but nothing that jumps out at me to produce the described behavior.

Comment: I had a similar problem with the exit command, so if anyone ever comes across it, turns out I was just missing a `exit()` call on an error check in my code, so the exit command was closing an instance that should've already been closed.

Answer (score 2):

Like the `cd` command, the `exit` command has to be interpreted by the shell as a built-in; it must exit the loop or call the `exit()` function directly.  However, it also appears that should be happening.  Note that using `strcoll()` is a little unusual; normally, `strcmp()` is sufficient.

You should report problems if `execvp()` returns — and you must make sure the sub-shell exits so that you don't have multiple shell processes reading the input simultaneously.   I'm left wondering if this problem is occurring, and that's why you have to type `exit` multiple times.

You also need to check that `fgets()` did not report an error.  It always null terminates its input; your code does not zap the newline (you'd need `strlen(buffer)-1` instead of `sizeof(buffer)-1`).

The code that reads and sets `PATH` is wrong.  `getenv("PATH")` returns a pointer to the first character after the `PATH=` part; you then use that to 'set' the environment.  Fortunately for you, the average value for PATH does not contain anything that looks like `VAR=value`, so it is functionally a no-op (though the information is probably copied into the environment, where it makes a mess without causing any major harm).

Your code indentation scheme is rococo at best — mostly, it is just woefully inconsistent.  Please be consistent!  The spacing of the lines in the code was also extremely erratic.  When you're adding code in SO, do not use tabs, do use 4 spaces per indent level, do highlight a block of code that is left justified and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it as code.  This also means you don't need to add blank lines to the code.

You aren't closing enough file descriptors.  When you use `dup()` (or `dup2()`) to duplicate a pipe to standard input or standard output, you have to close *both* of the file descriptors returned by `pipe()`.

On Linux, using `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour, AFAIK.  It is defined on Windows, but not on POSIX systems.

You don't check that your `chdir()` system call works.

---

Trying your code, I did get one runaway prompt.  Unfortunately, I couldn't remember or see what triggered the runaway.  The code below is mostly sanitized and seems to behave.  I've annotated some critical changes — and not others.  One of the things you should be doing for your own benefit is including trace like the `dump_cmd()` function so you can see what your program is doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *cmndtkn[256];
char  buffer[256];
char *path = NULL;
char  pwd[128];

static void dump_cmd(char **argv);

int main(void)
{
    /*
    //setting path variable
    char *env;
    env=getenv("PATH");
    putenv(env);
    system("clear");
    */

    printf("\t MY OWN SHELL !!!!!!!!!!\n ");
    printf("_______________________________________\n\n");

    while (1)
    {
        //fflush(stdin);
        getcwd(pwd, 128);
        printf("[MOSH~%s]$", pwd);

        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == 0)
        {
            putchar('\n');
            break;
        }
        //buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';
        buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';

        //tokenize the input command line
        char *tkn = strtok(buffer, " \t\n");
        int i = 0;
        int indictr = 0;

        // loop for every part of the command
        while (tkn != NULL)
        {
            if (strcoll(tkn, "exit") == 0)
            {
                printf("Got: exit\n");
                fflush(stdout);
                exit(0);
            }
            else if (strcoll(tkn, "cd") == 0)   // Was buffer, not tkn
            {
                printf("Got: cd (%s)\n", buffer + 3);
                fflush(stdout);
                path = buffer;
                chdir(path += 3);
            }
            else if (strcoll(tkn, "|") == 0)
            {
                indictr = i;
            }
            cmndtkn[i++] = tkn;
            tkn = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        }
        cmndtkn[i] = 0;

        // execute when command has pipe. when | command is found indictr is greater than 0.
        if (indictr > 0)
        {
            char *leftcmnd[indictr+1];
            char *rightcmnd[i-indictr];
            int a, b;

            for (b = 0; b < indictr; b++)
                leftcmnd[b] = cmndtkn[b];

            leftcmnd[indictr] = NULL;

            for (a = 0; a < i-indictr-1; a++)
                rightcmnd[a] = cmndtkn[a+indictr+1];

            rightcmnd[i-indictr-1] = NULL;  // Did not include -1

            if (!fork())
            {
                fflush(stdout);
                int pfds[2];
                pipe(pfds);

                if (!fork())
                {
                    dump_cmd(leftcmnd);
                    close(1);
                    dup(pfds[1]);
                    close(pfds[0]);
                    close(pfds[1]);
                    execvp(leftcmnd[0], leftcmnd);
                    fprintf(stderr, "failed to execvp() %s\n", leftcmnd[0]);
                    exit(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    dump_cmd(rightcmnd);
                    close(0);
                    dup(pfds[0]);
                    close(pfds[0]);
                    close(pfds[1]);
                    execvp(rightcmnd[0], rightcmnd);
                    fprintf(stderr, "failed to execvp() %s\n", rightcmnd[0]);
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            else
                wait(NULL);

        }
        else
        {
            //command does not include pipe
            if (!fork())
            {
                dump_cmd(cmndtkn);
                fflush(stdout);
                execvp(cmndtkn[0], cmndtkn);
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to execvp() %s\n", cmndtkn[0]);
                exit(1);
            }
            else
                wait(NULL);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static void dump_cmd(char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: Command:\n", (int)getpid());
    while (*argv != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: %d: [[%s]]\n", (int)getpid(), i++, *argv++);
}
```

I'm not keen on the code, but it does seem mostly sane.